# What is the meaning of the Port Number parameter in Window's ATL Winsock wrapper CSocketAddr::FindINET4Addr

Tags: winapi, network-programming, dns, ip-address, winsock

Is it the UDP port used to send out the DNS request, e.g. 53?  Or can a host name like example.com have a different IP address resolution based off the specific port being used, e.g. example.com port 80 is 1.2.3.4 but example.com port 25 is 5.6.7.8?  If so, then is this "port number" parameter the port specific name resolution?

This method eventually calls window's getaddrinfo where it ends up being the 2nd parameter const char* servname which is a string that is this integer port number as a string, e.g. "53" or "80".

Comment: It gets passed to getaddrinfo() which fills in an addrinfo struct which contains a sockaddr struct which has a field for the port number.  I suppose it is more of a convenience than anything else, saving you the trouble of having to remember to fill it in yourself later; it has no bearing on the actual DNS lookup.

Comment: @Luke: I understand that for getaddrinfo(), but the CSocketAddr C++ wrapper should have just stubbed it out if that is true.  I'm not saying you're not right, I'm just saying that the ATL C++ library designer should have "simplified" the query if that was true.  The fact that I don't find much on the Internet about FindINET4Addr tells me you could be correct.

Comment: 99.9% of the time you are just going to pass the addrinfo it gives you directly to connect(), so for the common case it makes sense to go ahead and fill in the port field (requiring a somewhat superfluous parameter).  The convenience far outweighs the "unclean" interface IMHO; then again, I am *extremely* lazy.

Comment: fyi, all of these port values work. I've passed in 80, 123 (to resolve an ntp server), and now I just pass in 0 all the time, and they all work, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

The port number is used when the flag parameter contains the `AI_NUMERICSERV` flag:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520.aspx:

> When the AI_NUMERICSERV bit is set, the pServiceName parameter must
>   contain a non-NULL numeric port number, otherwise the EAI_NONAME error
>   is returned. This flag prevents a name resolution service from being
>   called.
>
> The AI_NUMERICSERV flag is defined on Windows SDK for Windows Vista
>   and later. The AI_NUMERICSERV flag is not supported by Microsoft
>   providers.

Comment: That just states that the string contains a numeric port number (service).  What is the expected difference in behavior when the text is "53" vs. "80" vs. "25" vs. "110" to the host-name "google.com", when the flag parameter contains the AI_NUMERICSERV flag?

Comment: I have no clue what the parameter is used for.